# How do I get the recent blockhashses during program execution?

Tags: anchor, blockhash, sysvar

I want to get the latest blockhash (or last 10 or so) during program execution. The goal is prove that the tx was created and executed in real time. Here are the steps that I am thinking:

1. get latest blockhash on client
2. create tx using this blockhash on client
3. execute transaction with blockhash sent as a parameter of ix in tx
4. program fetches latest blockhash(es) and validates that inputted blockhash matches a recent blockhash

I found this but it is deprecated:[recent_blockhashes](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/sysvar/recent_blockhashes/struct.RecentBlockhashes.html)

I also found this but it says it cannot be used in a tx, only on an RPC: [slot_hashes](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/sysvar/slot_hashes/index.html#reexport.SlotHashes)

When I try to use `slot_hashes` in my anchor program I get this error:

```
> Program log: AnchorError caused by account: recent_slothashes. Error Code: AccountSysvarMismatch. Error Number: 3015. Error Message: The given public key does not match the required sysvar.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slot_hashes` sysvar is unfortunately too large to deserialize in an on-chain program.

You can partially deserialize it, however, to get a small number of the hashes. Here's an example, lifted from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3440/files

Of course, you won't go through the whole thing, but you can probably get through a good number of entries with this!

```
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let sysvar_slot_history = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    /*
        Decoding the SlotHashes sysvar using `from_account_info` is too expensive.
        For example this statement will exceed the current BPF compute unit budget:
            let slot_hashes = SlotHashes::from_account_info(&sysvar_slot_history).unwrap();
        Instead manually decode the sysvar.
    */

    if *sysvar_slot_history.key != sysvar::slot_hashes::id() {
        msg!("Invalid SlotHashes sysvar");
        return Err(ProgramError::InvalidArgument);
    }

    let data = sysvar_slot_history.try_borrow_data()?;

    let num_slot_hashes = u64::from_le_bytes(data[0..8].try_into().unwrap());
    let mut pos = 8;

    for _i in 0..num_slot_hashes {
        let slot = u64::from_le_bytes(data[pos..pos + 8].try_into().unwrap());
        pos += 8;
        let hash = &data[pos..pos + 32];
        pos += 32;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. this was helpful! i am still struggling to compare the values derived from the above code to `const {blockhash} = await connection.getLatestBlockhash()`. How would I do that?

Comment: You can pass in the blockhash as its underlying 32 bytes, and then compare them to the 32 bytes of the `hash` in the code example.

Comment: Thanks again for the response here... I might be missing something here: I can find the correct slot number (log the slot number in the program, and print it on the client side), but the hashes/buffers do not match. Why is that?

Comment: that is using the above code to print out slot numbers/slot hashes, and using `connection.getLatestBlockhash` on the client

Comment: Ah yes, this is a common misconception -- slot hashes are not the same as blockhashes! The slot hash is made up of the parent bank hash, current block hash, and a few other things. And the block hash is made up POH ticks during replay

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the help ser.